# Nodal Setup for Diffuse, Emission, Normal and Specular map in Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, normal-map

I downloaded a model from here: https://www.models-resource.com/mobile/marvelscontestofchampions/model/15341/

It has got 4 maps(with suffixes _d,_e,_n and _s).

[image: Diffuse Map]
[image: Emission Map]
[image: Normal Map]
[image: Specular Map]

I tried a nodal arrangement(which I bet isn't right) but i couldn't configure specular into it.
[image: Nodes]

The End Result:
[image: Render]

How do I add the Specular map and give it a metallic shine as seen in the linked page.
I am learning textures and materials and so a gist or any learning videos which might be helpful are encouraged.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This node setup works and it's a very basic one, tell me if you understand. Note that all the *Image Texture* nodes are supposed to be in *Non-Color Data* mode except the one for the *Diffuse* node. Also, I needed to put a *ColorRamp* node after the Specular *Image Texture* node to give more strength to the *Diffuse* node against the *Glossy* one.

If I explain quickly: I mix the *Diffuse Image Texture* with the *Glossy*, and use the *Specular* as the factor. This is basic: the *Specular* picture will determine what part of the object is glossy, what other part remain matt. But as the object was super glossy I had to adjust with a *Converter* > *ColorRamp* node after the *Specular*. Also, as I want both the *Glossy* and the *Diffuse* to be affected by a *Normal* map to give some fake 3D details, I needed to put the *Normal* Map in both the *Diffuse* and the *Glossy*. Now to finish the object you need to switch on the lights with an *Emission* shader: Just add a last *Mix Shader* and mix the *Emission* node and use the *Emission* map as the factor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: why the emission texture its in fac instead of the emission node color input?

Comment: it's obvious that the emission picture was supposed to be used as a mask layer to display a light on only some parts of the object. If you plug the emission picture in an emission node it will emit black and white, and it's not what you want, it will darken your image!

Comment: A minor nitpick, but the emission node should be using the diffuse colour texture as well to give a blueish tinge to the light. The specular texture is also coloured, which I believe should affect the glossy colour, which should in turn make the gold look more metallic.

Comment: Ok, I'm interested, perhaps make your own answer so that I could see what would be your node setup and give a try

Answer (score 2):

[image: final]

You can use **Principled BSDF** for easy setup.

**D - diffuse.**

Connect to **Diffuse** slot.

**S - specular.**

Read here about **Specular** in [**Principled BSDF**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/principled.html).

I've used it as **Specular Tint** (this one from your example is color one) to give reflections nice color tint and also with the help of **Color Ramp** I've used it as **Roughness** input. It gives nice control over reflections in non-uniform way.

Set it as **Non-color data**.

**N - normal.**

Connect it to **Normal** slot with **Normal Map** node.

Set it as **Non-color data**.

**E - emission.**

In this case use it as layer mask between **Principled BSDF** and **Emission** shader.

[image: nodes]